# Transformation in custom fluent validator rule

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, validation, fluentvalidation

I use FluentValidation v10.4.0. How can I create own custom rule with preliminary transformation ?

```
  public static IRuleBuilderOptionsConditions<T, string> SomeRuleName<T>(
        this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder, Expression<Func<T, string>> expression)
    {
        return ruleBuilder
            // error happens below. Transform is not included in IRuleBuilderOptionsConditions 
            .Transform(expression, value => 
            {
                // some transformation
            })
            .NotEmpty();
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class MyValidator : AbstractValidator<MyClassToValidate>
    {
        public MyValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x).CustomAsync(async (model, context, cancellationToken) =>
            {}
         }
     }
```

You can instantiate the class or register it in startup class using **AddFluentValidation()** method.

Comment: Note: If you want it as middleware, better use the sync API.